# Symfony 2.8 - Datadog audit bundle retrieve entity

Tags: symfony

I used the [DataDog Audit bundle](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/DataDogAuditBundle) in order to log every action that happens in my MySQL database. However when I check the diff column in the audit_log table I can't find the ID of the respective entity that have been updated/inserted/deleted etc. I also can't find which user is responsible for a certain action. Does anyone know if the DataDog audit bundle saves the ID of the entity to which action are performed and if this is the case where I can retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does have this functionality in the Audit Association entity. The entity stored with the blame_id in the Audit Log entity contains information regarding the user. The one with source_id contains information regarding the entity itself and thus the ID of the entity in the `fk` field.